# Apparent SSH anomaly

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, openssh

I have four machines on which I'm installing Debian 11.2. On three of them, there was nothing I wanted to save, so I just did a clean install. On the fourth (10.0.0.96) I needed to save some stuff so I upgraded from Debian 9.3.

Everything went fine, except I can't SSH in to 10.0.0.96. I can ping it from my Win 10 machine and from the other Debian 11.2 machines (and I can ping them from it), but SSH just hangs. I can SSH in to the other three machines with no problem. I can even SSH in to them from 10.0.0.96.

I went so far as to `apt-get --purge openssh-server`, `apt-get autoremove`, and `apt-get install openssh.server`. I also compared the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` files of the four Debian 11.2 machines - they're all identical except for the ListenAddress.

I checked systemctl status ssh and it reports that it is listening on 10.0.0.96 port 22.

I can SSH in to 10.0.0.96 from itself, but not from the Win 10 machine, nor from any of the other three Debian 11 machines.

All four Debian 11 machines and the Win 10 machine are in the same room and are connected via cat-5 ethernet.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Dummy! (slapping my forehead with heel of palm):

```
sudo ufw deny 2296   

sudo ufw allow 22
```

Comment: *Physical Violence in answers is strictly against community rules. Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1708096/edit) your answer to remove the description of Incidents of violence that may have occurred or will occur in the future*

Comment: @SaaranshGarg you do realise this is the long form of the widely accepted (and non violent) :facepalm: response, right? Captain Picard is facepalming right now :)

Comment: @mdavdidjohnson I was going to suggest checking the host machine, but it looks like you got it sorted :)

Comment: @SaaranshGarg I've edited the question to make clear that OP is indeed slapping **his own** forehead to avoid any further misunderstandings.